# Xamarin.Forms conflict between PanGesture and TapGesture

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

This is my XAML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="App1.Views.ItemsPage"
             Title="{Binding Title}"
             x:Name="BrowseItemsPage">
    <StackLayout>
        <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
            <PanGestureRecognizer PanUpdated="PanGestureRecognizer_PanUpdated"/>
        </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
        <Label Text="111111111111111111111111111111">
            <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>
            </Label.GestureRecognizers>
        </Label>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

End the behind-code

```
private void PanGestureRecognizer_PanUpdated(object sender, PanUpdatedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now} pan");
        }

        private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DisplayAlert("Alert", "You have been alerted", "OK");
        }
```

When I run above code, at the first pan gesture I make a Pan on the Label and swipe down the **PanGestureRecognizer_PanUpdated** is **NOT** fired. It's only fired when I tap outside the Label then start a pan gesture on the Label.

Then I remove the TapGestureRecognizer's Label, and make a Pan on the Label and swipe down the **PanGestureRecognizer_PanUpdated** is fired.

It's conflict between Tap vs Pan gesture ?

P/s: I want to make a list swipe up/down-able (the container, in this case is StackLayout), and the items are clickable. I'm not using the ListView, because I'm making custom library

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected results . When you make the pan on label,the first register object is the `Label` , not the `StackLayout` .So the event will never been called .

**Solution:** You can put the StackLayout in a ScrollView . And add the **PullToRefresh** event on it .

Here is a [plugin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Refractored.XamForms.PullToRefresh/2.4.1.1-beta) which can add Pull to Refresh to ScrollView .

```
<controls:PullToRefreshLayout
          IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"
          RefreshCommand="{Binding RefreshCommand}"
          IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy}"
          RefreshColor="Blue"> 
          <ScrollView
          HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
          VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

            <StackLayout>   
              <Label Text="111111111111111111111111111111">
                <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                   <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>
                </Label.GestureRecognizers>
              </Label>
            </StackLayout>

          </ScrollView>
</controls:PullToRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: I don't want to use PullToRefresh it's not relative to my problems.

Comment: The problem is i'm not using the PullTORefreshLayout, i make a page transform animation. not a listview

Comment: If you want achieve the  animation when navigation to a new page , you can use the plugin https://github.com/AlexandrNikulin/AnimationNavigationPage .